# TableView - Multiple cells handling

Tags: ios, swift2, uitableview

I have a tableview and I have one section and two cells. First cell is for showing a division name and second cell is for showing corresponding district's name.

```
var  Division = [“Dhaka”,”Khulna”]
var  Districts = [[“Gazipur”,”Gopalganj”,”Faridpur”],[“Bagerhat”,”Jessor”,”Chuadanga”]]
```

I need to present in  table view like this.

```
Dhaka
Gazipur
Gopalganj
Faridpur

Khulna
Bagerhat
Jessor
Chuadanga
```

At first I was approaching like a traditional way but I could not move forward when it was necessary to define at  `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and `numberOfRowsInSection` protocol :(

Please suggest any way. Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: Instead of 1 section and 2 cells use 2 sections with 'n' cells. 'n' is the number of cells in each section.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right

Here division will be your section header

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int 
{
  return Division.count
}
```

and district will be your rows

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
   {
return Districts.count
}
```

For Displaying dont forget to add method for returning view for header and cellForRowAtIndexPath.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView?{
}
```

Comment: Thanks..but I need only one section...difficult to move forward  :(

Comment: Main header can be your tableview header and Division will be your section header. If you show me any image or any figure (what you want to make), then I can help you in better way.

Answer (score 0):

For the number of sections you can use:

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int
{
    return Districts.count
}
```

Then, to specify the number of rows in each section you can use:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return Districts[section].count
}
```

and finally you can setup your cell like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = self.TableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as! TableViewCell
    let cellText = Districts[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
    cell.Label.text = cellText
    return cell
}
```

For the TableView Header you can write this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String?
{
    if section < Division.count
    {
        print(Division[section])
        return Division[section]
    }
    else
    {
        return nil
    }
}
```

And your TableViewCell class is:

```
import UIKit

class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell
{
@IBOutlet weak var Label: UILabel!
override func awakeFromNib()
{
    super.awakeFromNib()
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool)
{
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

}

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort but I wanted to do it in only one section with two cell. First cell is for Division name and second Cell is for their respective cities.